# Trigger update same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table named 'item' which stores the amount and availability of an item along with a couple other things

I'm trying to create a trigger which when the 'item_amount' gets to 0, the 'item_available' sets also to 0 however I'm getting an error with the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER itemAvailability
AFTER UPDATE ON item
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE item
SET NEW.item_available=0
WHERE NEW.item_amount<=0
```

The error is

> #1442 - Can't update table 'item' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: Don't use an `UPDATE` statement. Use an `IF` statement that just assign the value `0` to `new.item_available` when `new.item_amount <= 0`. But having that column `item_available` int the table is violating normalization as it is fully dependent of `item_amount`. Best thing would be to drop `item_available` which also renders the need of the trigger obsolete. You can simply check for the availability in your queries by checking if `item_amount` is greater than zero.

Comment: Think im going to end up removing the field really, believe i just added as i need to include a trigger and just seemed like the easiest option, evidently not. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it seems like both columns mean the same thing.